# DNS zone record pointing to two different IP Addresses

Tags: dns, cross-domain

I know this had been already ask a couple of times but all the answer I find doesn't seem to work.(See More: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/50103/33973)

What A or CNAME DNS Zone Records should I put so these two conditions will work:
(1)If my domain "this.us" is opened without the `www`, I want to point the domain to the bit.ly server: `69.58.188.49`
(2)But if my domain is opened with `www` (www.this.us), I want to point the domain to a different server: `1.2.3.4`

```
This is what I've done so far:

A Record
@    69.58.188.49   
www  1.2.3.4
```

But everytime I open my domain on a web browser, both domain with and without `www`, seems to open bit.ly instead of the two conditions stated above.

Comment: currently both this.us and www.this.es resolve to 82.98.86.170. Is it a real domain in qustion or just a fake name ? Use example.net for such examples.

Comment: sorry i just used "this.us" domain for this scenario. The real domain I am using is glnr.us

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment above. However, I took a look after you provided your domain.

I'd recommend you check your dns records again. I see glnr.us pointing to a 185.* IP address. www.glnr.us is also hitting the same IP address because theres a CNAME record (alias) pointing it to glnr.us.

So your current set up is:

glnr.us resolves to 185.* IP.
www.glnr.us -> glnr.us -> 185.* IP address. This is aliased to glnr.us via the CNAME record. With this record, you are essentially re-directing www.glnr.us to glnr.us (without the www).

Remove the CNAME and create a new A record for "www.glnr.us" and point it to the desired IP address.